# PHP split string before and after the integer inside

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

> some address number 23 neighborhood city

Now, my goal is to separate it in two parts:

1. > some address number 23
2. > neighborhood city

I am guessing this will require a combination of the `split` or `preg_replace` commands using something like this `/[^0-9]/`. No matter how I tried, I did not get the desired result.

Edit: There is 2 absolute correct answers, One using preg_replace and the another one preg_split, Good luck !

Comment: I would rather match than split ... something trivial such as `(.+[0-9]+)(.+)` might basically do already.

Comment: Use `[0-9]+` to match your integer, then split after the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with flags (`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`)

```
<?php
$word= "some address number 23 neighborhood city";
$keywords = preg_split("/(.+[0-9]+)(.+)/", $word,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($keywords);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1006421

Explanation:-

```
/(.+[0-9]+)(.+)/

    1st Capturing Group (.+[0-9]+)

        .+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
            + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

        Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]+

            + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

    2nd Capturing Group (.+)
        .+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know preg_split could be used like this, thanks ! Now it its hard to select the best answers between you guys.

Comment: @DanielIliaguev  i ahve added the explanation of regex too

Comment: @AlivetoDie he says he wants to separate into 2 parts if there is 2 different numeric values this regex will separate it into 3 parts.

Comment: @AlivetoDie is there efficiency difference betweeb preg_match  and   preg_split for this case ?

Comment: @DanielIliaguev  no not at all

Answer (score 3):

```
$example = preg_split('/(?<=\d\D)/', 'some address number 23 neighborhood city', 2);

var_dump($example);


array(2) {   
[0]=>   string(20) "some address number 23 "   
[1]=> string(20) "neighborhood city" }
```

Comment: This is definitely the neatest option, but it puts the 23 on the wrong side. I think you might want something like `(?<=\d\D)` (i.e. positive lookbehind instead of ahead)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) and [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to match the string properly.

https://3v4l.org/K1IK4

```
<?php

$string = "some address number 23 neighborhood city";

preg_match("/([^\d]*\d*)(.*)$/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

---

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(40) "some address number 23 neighborhood city"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "some address number 23"
    [2]=>
    string(18) " neighborhood city"
}
```

**EDIT:**

In regex we want to achieve what we want with the lowest steps possible.

This is our regex: https://regex101.com/r/rihbWM/2 and we can see it requires **9** steps which is kinda good.

> 1st Capturing Group ([^\d]*\d*)
>
> Match a single character not present in the list below [^\d]* **This is performance-wise better than .*\d because .*\d matches the whole string - then has to jump back to the decimal which is worse performance-wise.**
>
> - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>
> \d* matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>
> - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> 2nd Capturing Group (.*)
>
> .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Comment: Thanks but 2 things, can you explain how you chose to use "/([^\d]*)\d*(.*)$/" ? I would really like to understand that part.. and Second it removes the number from the string, look at the example I need it to be "some address 23" can you tell me how to change that.

Comment: @DanielIliaguev Sure, just add the number into the capture group, I edited my answer. I will add in an explanation on why we choose this regex in a second.

Comment: @DanielIliaguev Added an explanation for the regex.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That sure helps allot to understanding this ! You make me hard time to choose the best answer between all of you... (They all works and detailed explained! )

Answer (score 0):

For the tidiest output, split on the space that follows the number.  By using `\K` in the pattern, you release the matched number and only consume the space while exploding.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ma84h))

```
var_export(
    preg_split("/\d+\K /", $address)
);
```

If you KNOW that you only want two elements and there might be two separate integers in the string, just set the element limit parameter of `preg_split()` to `2`.

```
preg_split("/\d+\K /", $address, 2)
```